# How to use RxJava or Observables to listen for a variable change in a different class?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am attempting to do a login for an android app. My problem is that when I call login from Activity.java, the Service.java method uses call.enqueue from Retrofit and it is async. So I am not able to wait and consume the response in the Activity.java method (so that I can handle what happens next).

Therefore, I decided that if I can setup a listener of some sort to capture when the response object changes, that I can handle what happens next in the app.

I have been looking into RxJava but no examples that I have seen work across multiple classes or seem to actually work properly. It would be extremely helpful to have some basic syntax that I could apply to this that would allow me to consume the login response object so that I can handle what happens next in the application. I am not married to RxJava either so if there is a different way to approach this that will let me consume this object, I'm fine with that. Thanks!!

GlobalData.java

```
public class GlobalData {
    public static LoginResponse globalResponse;
}
```

Activity.java

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Can I subscribe here and do some logic for when globalResponse changes?!?
    } 

    public void login() {
        // create login request object
        // ...

        // call service method
        LoginResponse response = service.loginMethod(request);

        // Can I await the async in loginMethod so that I run logic after the call?
    }
}
```

Service.java

```
public class Service implements ServiceInterface {
    @Override
    public loginMethod(LoginRequest request) {
        // Setup Retrofit for api call
        // ...
        Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.login(request);

        // async call to get a response from the api for login
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                GlobalData.globalResponse = response.body(); // updates global data variable with the response from login
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the next blogs to know how use Rx and retrofit together

Rxjava & Retrofit: http://www.baeldung.com/retrofit-rxjava

How subscribe an observable object: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html#creating-observables-subscribing-to-them-and-disposing-them

I think with that you can continue with you login flow

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Can I subscribe here and do some logic for when globalResponse changes?!?
```

Yes, but only if you use a `BehaviorSubject`/`BehaviorRelay` (I vote [Relay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay), see [BehaviorRelay](http://jakewharton.github.io/RxRelay/com/jakewharton/rxrelay2/BehaviorRelay.html)).

So you have

```
public class GlobalData {
    private GlobalData() {}

    public static LoginResponse globalResponse;
}
```

But it should be something like

```
public class GlobalData {
    private GlobalData() {}

    public static BehaviorRelay<Optional<LoginResponse>> globalResponse = BehaviorRelay.createDefault(Optional.absent());
}
```

And

```
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            LoginResponse login = response.body();
            if(login != null) {
                GlobalData.globalResponse.accept(Optional.of(response.body()); 
            }
        }
```

Bonus points if you hide the Relay and expose a method that writes into it, and another that shows it as `Observable<Optional<T>>`.

Anyways now you can do

```
Disposable disposable = GlobalData.globalResponse.subscribe((opt) -> {
    if(opt.isPresent()) {
        LoginResponse data = opt.get();
        // do whatever
    }
});
```